# terminal command for mysql file import

Tags: mysql

I am trying to import a 60 MB file, *filename-20120201.tbz*, into a newly created MySQL database. I am using terminal, and have opened the database by the prompt use new_database.

How do I import this file correctly? I am on a Mac. Thanks.

Answer (score 27):

If you are running mysql and using your newly created database use the below code to run the script file

```
mysql> SOURCE input_file
```

or from terminal

```
mysql -u root -p database < filename-20120201.tbz
```

Answer (score 11):

Try

```
$ mysql -u root -p new_database < db-dump.sql
```

Where:
   new_database is the name of your new database and 
   db-dump.sql is the mysql file to be imported

Answer (score 3):

This should do the trick:

```
\. filename
```

(provided within MySQL's command line, assuming `filename` is SQL file)

Comment: Thanks! This is excelent for SQL data dumps with automatic database creation like `CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS`

Answer (score 0):

Place the password immediately after `-p`

```
mysql -u root -ppassword database < file.sql
```

Comment: Is this safe? What if somebody reads your terminal history? Or simply reads while you're typing.

Comment: @AxelA.Grazx : nice comment... does that mean you will keep people around while typing password or command? **does anyone see when you type your twitter password?**

Comment: I'm just saying that `mysql -u root -p database < file.sql` will ask your password in a safer way. And if somebody see you typing your Twitter password they would see ***********. Just a little peek on `-pMyMySQLPassword` would be needed to know your password. And excuse me if this comments sounds rude ;)